# Pandas: Iterate through columns and starting at one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know how to incorporate a forloop for columns but start at any column? (The third one for this scenario)

Lets say this is the dataframe:

```
spice smice skice bike dike mike 
1     23     35    34   34   56 
135   34     23    21   56   34
231   12     67    21   62   75
```

I want to iterate through **skice, bike, dike, and mike *only***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `df.columns` provides you the list of columns, you can do below and iterate from 3rd column name.

```
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    #print(df[col].unique())
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use .unique for each of the col in this loop? like col.unique()

Comment: Ofcourse. you can do `print(df[col].unique())` in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

More general solutions if the columns are not consecutive:

```
l = ['skice', 'bike', 'dike','mike']
cols = df.columns.intersection(l)
for col in cols:
    print (col)
```