# How to obtain output files labeled with dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas

I am  a python/pandas user and I have a multiple dataframe like df1, df2,df3....
I want to name them as A, B, C, ... thus I wrote as below.

```
df_dict = {"A":df1, "B":df2,'C':df3,....}
```

Each dataframe has "Price" column and I want to know the output from the following formula.

```
frequency=df.groupby("Price").size()/len(df)
```

I made the following definition and want to obtain outputs from each dataframe.

```
def Price_frequency(df,keys=["Price"]):
    frequency=df.groupby(keys).size()/len(df)
    return frequency.reset_index().to_csv("Output_%s.txt" %(df),sep='\t')
```

As a first trial, I did 
    Price_frequency(df1,keys=["Price"])
but this did not work. It seems %s is wrong.

Ideally, I want output files named as "Output_A.txt", "Output_B.txt"...
If you could help me, I would be grateful for that very much.

Comment: %s expects a string and your passing a DataFrame

Comment: you could iterate through the columns to get what you're after

Comment: I got you. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. `%s` requires you to input a string. But in Python 3.6+ you can use formatted string literals, which you may find more readable.
2. Your function doesn't need to return anything here. You are using it to output csv files in a loop. Don't feel the need to add a `return` statement if it doesn't serve a purpose.

So you can do the following:

```
def price_frequency(df_dict, df_name, keys=['Price']):
    frequency = df_dict[df_name].groupby(keys).size() / len(df_dict[df_name].index)
    frequency.reset_index().to_csv(f'Output_{df_name}.txt', sep='\t')

df_dict = {'A': df1, 'B': df2, 'C': df3}

for df_name in df:
    price_frequency(df_dict, df_name, keys=['Price'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through columns will get output.

```
def Price_frequency(df):
    for col in df.columns[2:]
        frequency=df.groupby(col).size()/len(df)

    return frequency.reset_index().to_csv("Output_%s.txt" %(col),sep='\t')
```

Reference: [Pandas: Iterate through columns and starting at one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408351/pandas-iterate-through-columns-and-starting-at-one-column)

Note: haven't gotten to test this yet